# How to get around value for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are several related questions on stackoverflow.  But I've gone through them and still the facebook debugger brings up this error.

I have a business FB account and not personal.  I tried the admin ID, username and app ID, since I'm using several apps on the page.  All return this same error.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: _“I have a business FB account and not personal.”_ – then _get_ a personal one. Everyone who wants to “administer” anything on Facebook has to be a real person.

Comment: Worked.  Can you post as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a business FB account and not personal.

Then get a personal one. Everyone who wants to “administer” anything on Facebook has to be a real person.